# New instance of extended object in Kotlin

Tags: spring-data, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin coming from Groovy. As a way to study the language I'm trying to reproduce a few small Groovy examples on Kotlin.

Consider the following:

```
@Entity
data class Person(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long = 0,

        var name: String = "",

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
        var contacts: MutableList<BaseContact>? = null
) : BaseEntity()


@Entity
@Inheritance
open class BaseContact(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long = 0,

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        var person: Person
)

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("email")
data class Email(
        var address: String = ""
) : BaseContact()

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("phone")
data class Phone(
        var number: String = ""
) : BaseContact()
```

I have a few Spring Data applications that I'm trying to reproduce in Kotlin and some of them use @Inheritance. The "problem" I'm having is that an Email always have to have a Person. But Email get that property from BaseContact so I can't do something like the bellow because "person" is not part of the constructor.

```
val john = Person(name = 'John')
val email = Email(address = 'john@mail.com', person = john)
```

This will work though:

```
val email = Email(address = 'john@mail.com')
email.person = john
```

Because after the email is instantiated I can now access the "person" property.

Is there any way on Kotlin for me to achieve a more "Groovy-like" way to instantiate new objects without having to create many overrides for it's constructor? I'm specially interested on the case of extended classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to initialize the properties after an object is instantiated is using the [`.apply { }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) extension function:

```
val john = Person(name = "John")

val email = Email(address = "john@mail.com").apply {
     person = john
     /* more initialization in scope of `email` */
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've been doing something like 'Email().apply { address = "what@what.com", otherThing = "etc..." }' but I considered it a bit ugly so I was trying to find something like I described above.